# Cannot connect to MongoDB with Sitecore

Tags: mongodb, sitecore

I'm working on a Sitecore website (Sitecore 8 Update 2).

I installed MongoDB, and I can connect to localhost:27017 with Robomongo and MongoVUE, but this is all I get.

[image: Robomongo UI]

I hooked up Sitecore to MongoDB with these connection strings:

```
<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/kbs_analytics" />
<add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/kbs_tracking_live" />
<add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/kbs_tracking_history" />
<add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/kbs_tracking_contact" />
```

But it doesn't seem to link up.

As far as I can tell, once I have the connection string, Sitecore should at the very least start creating some collections in the database. But this doesn't happen, and I don't get any error messages.

Does anyone know what could cause this, or what I might have forgotten?

Comment: Can you check the file Sitecore.Analytics.config and see if the setting "Analytics.Enabled" is set to true?

Comment: what version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: Just clarification: it should create databases and collections inside them.  Not only collections.

Comment: Anything Mongo related in the logs?

Comment: It turns out sitecore 8 doesn't support the latest version of mongoDB ( 3.0.4 ) so far they only support up to 2.6.x

Comment: I had the same issue with MongoDB 3 too, rolling back to 2.6 fixed the issue.

Comment: You need to update the Mongo client to v1.10 to connect to Mongo 3+. It doesn't look like you have any authentication in place, but if you go there don't use the newer authentication mechanisms (e.g. `SCRAM`) but configure the default back to `MONGODB-CR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sitecore 8 Update 5 there is support for MongoDB 3.0.

For older versions:

Sitecore is using MongoDB.Driver.dll version 1.8.3.9 in Sitecore 7.5 - 8.0 update 4, this is not working with MongoDB 3.

You can update the C# Mongo drivers in Sitecore. See [sitecore-on-mongodb-3-0-what-should-you-know](http://www.sitecoreblog.cz/en/sitecore-on-mongodb-3-0-what-should-you-know/)

Or use MongoDB 2.6.x [sitecore experience platform/xdb overview/software recommendations](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/xdb%20overview/software%20recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to ensure if you have enabled tracking on your sitecore CD Server.
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/xdb_configuration/configure_a_content_delivery_server

I think you don't need to specify the port number just machine name is enough. By default Sitecore uses 27017 as the port to connect to MongoDB. Also ensure if the machine on which you have installed MongoDB has this port 27017  open.

Comment: I accepted the correct answer to my problem months ago...
It was incompatiable versions that was the issue here.